# Thread priorities

Tags: c#, multithreading

How big difference is it between `ThreadPriority.Lowest` and `ThreadPriority.BelowNormal`.

How do I know which one to choose? I have some CPU intensive calculations and I do not want them to effect the rest of the application.

**Update**

The job is being invoked from a `System.Threading.Timer`.  Do I have to reset the thread priority before the callback method returns, or will .Net handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Darin and Matt's answers are entirely correct, and probably complete. I'm just adding on some extra words here :p

The basic idea is that the priorities only truly have meaning in relation to each other. Work of lower priorities (effectively) won't get done until there is no more work at higher priorities needing to be done. This is why it's so dangerous to boost priorities of processes/threads too high - you could effectively lock up the rest of the system.

Note also that your thread priority affects the rest of the system - not just the rest of your application. But also note that the OS itself is free to adjust the relative priorities of threads on-the-fly (which is why I keep using the word "effectively").

Comment: So setting a thread priority to lower doesn't only change how it's handled in the application but also relative to threads in other processes?

Comment: @jgauffin - Absolutely; keeping in mind that the OS can apply its own adjustments to threads in any process as it sees fit. But this is why, for example, the Windows Task Manager (taskmgr.exe) sets its default priority to "High"; so threads in it have a greater chance to be run even if the system is being pegged at 100% cpu due to some out-of-control program.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at? [MSDN Thread Priority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpriority.aspx)

> Threads are scheduled for execution based on their priority. The scheduling algorithm used to determine the order of thread execution varies with each operating system. The operating system can also adjust the thread priority dynamically as the user interface's focus is moved between the foreground and the background.

Specific to your question:

> Lowest    The Thread can be scheduled after threads with any other priority.
>
> BelowNormal   The Thread can be scheduled after threads with Normal priority and before those with Lowest priority.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpriority.aspx) seems pretty clear. Use `Lowest` if you want threads to be scheduled after threads with any other priority. Use `BelowNormal` if you want threads to be scheduled after threads with `Normal` priority and before those with `Lowest` priority.

Comment: So it only matters if I've specified priority for other threads in the application?

Comment: Yes, have in mind that .Net will create other threads on you application as well for things like GC and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful setting the thread priority though.

While you don't want the process to affect the rest of the application's responsiveness, by reducing the thread priority it could well mean that the thread takes a lot longer to complete. This could have an apparently more serious impact on the application as the user is more obviously waiting for it to complete.

You should test the effect of changing the priority on different machines with different loads. Setting the priority to lowest will have a significant impact on the thread's execution time.

You may also want to consider having an option (which may be hidden to some degree) allowing the user to control the thread priority (or at least choose between 2 or 3 of the middle values.

Comment: Thanks for raising those issues but this job is in a windows service / COM+ application where time is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Which one to choose depends on your situation, but I view it this way:

If the process is entirely background and isn't too critical, Lowest.

If the process needs to happen, but time isn't critical, Below Normal.

If the process is just as important as everything else, Normal.

I try not to use the higher ones, my programs are not *that* important :)

As for the difference, this depends on the code running and what the OS decides to do with the priorities, it doesn't need to listen to the one you set.